# Deploying react app with nginx by using s2i strategy in OpenShift

Tags: openshift-3, openshift-enterprise, s2i

I want to deploy my react app by using s2i strategy from local directory that includes build files to openshift.(OpenShift 3.11 version)

Firstly, I created a build-config file by using oc-cli tool

```
oc new-build nginx:1.12--name=s2i-frontend--binary=true
```

It's ok. After I have created **builder image** sucessfully that called **nginx:1.12**, switch path which includes build files of react app that creates after npm run build phase. I typed the following command

```
oc start-build s2i-frontend --from-dir=build/ --wait --loglevel=10
```

but I came across an error like that:

my code is [here](https://github.com/fthgul/docker-react.)

> Response Body:
>   {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"unable
>   to wait for build s2i-frontend-15 to run: timed out waiting for the
>   condition","reason":"BadRequest","code":400}
>
> Uploading finished I0129 11:40:28.529232   31060 helpers.go:201]
>   server response object: [{   "metadata": {},   "status": "Failure",
>   "message": "unable to wait for build s2i-frontend-15 to run: timed out
>   waiting for the condition",   "reason": "BadRequest",   "code": 400 }]
>   F0129 11:40:28.530229   31060 helpers.go:119] Error from server
>   (BadRequest): unable to wait for build s2i-frontend-15 to run: timed
>   out waiting for the condition

Answer (score 0):

I have opened an issue to [github](https://github.com/openshift/source-to-image/issues/1015) for this problem and I was warned.Then I have controlled my configuration resources. I have got the problem which is about the resource quota definitions configs. The problem is solved and run successfully.